# Linear model within a loop (loop used to subset data)

Tags: r, loops, gradient, subset, lm

I have (what I think should be) a straight forward problem in R, and can't seem to get it to work. Hope you can help.

I have a data frame e.g.:

```
x  y  z
1  2  a
2  3  a
3  4  a
4  5  b
5  6  b
6  7  b      etc...
```

And I'm fitting a linear model (y ~ x) for each z value subset (e.g. a, b...) and extracting the gradient.

It works when I select 'a' using a with statement as such:

```
coef(with(subset(data.frame, z == "a"), {lm(y ~ x)
}))[2]
```

But my problem is that I have more than 1000 unique values in the Z column. So I tried to set up a loop (I know R users hate loops!) to do this for each value of z in turn and return the result in a data frame. Code is:

```
gradient.lm = NULL

unique.z <- as.matrix((unique(data.frame$z)))
count.z <- nrow(unique.z)

for (i in 1:count.z) {
  gradient.lm[i] = coef((with(subset(data.frame, z == [i]), {lm(y ~ z)
  })))[2]
}
```

But this is not working, and giving me the error code:

```
> for (i in 1:count.z) {
+   activity.lm[i] = coef((with(subset(data.frame, z == [i]), {lm(y ~ x)
Error: unexpected '[' in:
"for (i in 1:count.z) {
  activity.lm[i] = coef((with(subset(data.frame, z == ["
>   })))[2]
Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

My guess was that it doesn't realise that there is an [i] within the with function.

I can't find a way of making this work, or think of another way of doing it. If you have any suggestions they would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: use `z == unique.z[i]` instead of `z == [i]`

Comment: (And it's generally bad practice to name variables like functions (`data.frame`))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base-R, getting you a named vector of only the gradients you're apparently interested in:

```
gradient.lm <- unlist(lapply(split(df,df$z),function(chunk){
  return(coef(lm(y~x, data=chunk))[[2]])
}))
```

Comment: Heroka, that seems to work perfect. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2):

I'd strongly recommend a `dplyr` and `broom` package solution:

```
set.seed(44)

dt = data.frame(x = rnorm(40, 5, 5),
                y = rnorm(40, 3, 4),
                z = rep(c("a","b"), 20))

library(dplyr)
library(broom)

dt %>%
  group_by(z) %>%            # group by column z
  do(tidy(lm(y~x, data=.)))  # for each group create model using corresponding x and y values

# Source: local data frame [4 x 6]
# Groups: z [2]
# 
#        z        term    estimate std.error  statistic    p.value
#   (fctr)       (chr)       (dbl)     (dbl)      (dbl)      (dbl)
# 1      a (Intercept)  3.54448459 1.8162699  1.9515186 0.06673401
# 2      a           x -0.18140655 0.2260252 -0.8025944 0.43267918
# 3      b (Intercept)  1.69024601 1.1960922  1.4131402 0.17467413
# 4      b           x  0.02647677 0.1914492  0.1382966 0.89154143
```

You can extract any piece of information of the `lm` output you want.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
unique_z = unique(df$z)
coef_vec = vector(mode = "list", length = length(unique_z))

coef_vec[1] = 
for (i in unique_z){
  coef_vec[i] = 
    coef(
      with(
        subset(df, z==i), 
      {lm(y~x)}))[2]
}

print(coef_vec)
```

Cleary `coef_vec[i]` corresponds to the z value in `unique_z[i]` so you have the coefficients matched up to their `z` values.

Comment: Your solution doesn't return or assign anything.

Comment: @Heroka you can easily do that no? I'll modify it to put it all in a vector if you like.